# What USB thumb drive parameters are relevant to the perfomance of linux OS running on it?

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media, usb-3

How and what parameters of a USB stick would influence the performance of a development oriented (or cutting edge) linux distro installed on it? 4k read/writes, sequential ones, chunk size, something else?

Comment: Are you talking about specific file movement tasks or selecting/preparing the flash drive for normal use?  The kinds of parameters you mention aren't relevant to drive selection/preparation.  Chip speed, capacity, and filesystem are drive parameters that could be relevant to Linux operational performance.  Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @fixer1234 I want to install Arch linux on a flash drive, probably going to do mostly cpu intensive tasts on it, with an occasional (big) compile job. I'm asking what should the usb drive I buy be like. What should I order in other words (with a failry limited budged (around 30 euro)). But that's the specifics. I was asking more about what tasks (in linux) need what kind of I/O so I could get a flash drive that lands in the middle of the bell curve of I/O operations of a casual developper.

Comment: Just get a high speed drive with a lot of capacity from a reputable manufacturer.  Have a way to back it up frequently and assume that it will fail sooner than you expect.  Flash drives aren't reliable and don't make great working drives for anything mission critical.  There aren't really parameters beyond that that will make a lot of difference between alternative drives.

Comment: @fixer1234 is that high top speed, high sequential speed, high random write/read speed, or some other measure of speed?

Comment: Look from the other direction.  Advertising claims are spotty & unreliable.  Compare 3rd party testing/reviews.  Google flash drive speed tests.  You'll find sites like: http://usb.userbenchmark.com/, http://www.flashdrivespeed.com/, http://usbspeed.nirsoft.net/.  Look at what drives you can find reviews/tests for, drive availability, performance comparison, & prices.  Eliminate less-good choices & bad reviews.  That will narrow it down to a few stand-outs.  Only if those have disparate read vs. write speed benefits, will you need to look at which speed might be more beneficial for your usage.